# MDL Why the use of is-visible instead of --visible modifier

Tags: naming-conventions, material-design, material-design-lite, bem

Asking on here as opposed to repo as per contributing.md.

I noticed that on most elements `.mdl-layout__obfuscator` for example an `.is-visible` class is added to make this object visible.

I was curious as to why you do not use a modifier to achieve this i.e:

```
.mdl-layout__obfuscator .mdl-layout__obfuscator--visible
```

Is there any particular reason for this?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Because state-classes are intended for elements, what can change his state. Those can have or not have this „--visible“ modifier.
See example to feel the difference between modifier and state class: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/91bebd16ce4bbb7d6a45

Btw, canonical BEM doesn't have state classes, but some BEM realizations like SMACSS or Harry Robert's BEMIT — does. MDL is also a one of the BEM realizations, so you should not thinking about it like a mandatory rule.